# WinUAE telnet from serial.device

Tags: modem, telnet, amiga, bbs

I want to "call" a telnet BBS from my NComm running on WinUAE. Have someone achieved this and if so - how ?

Answer (score 0):

Install telser and tell NComm to use telser.device as its serial

- http://aminet.net/package/comm/tcp/telser140
- http://aminet.net/package/comm/tcp/Telser_Keyfile

NComm can then be used to telnet out using modem-style AT commands.

```
atd server.com
```

Comment: what is telser?

Comment: To quote the link: telser.device  ("telser")  is  a  modem  simulator  running over a TCP
telnet/rlogin  connection.   It  simulates  basic `modem commands', so
telecommunication ("comm") programs can run over a network connection.
To  the  comm  program,  it  thinks it's talking to a modem.  Terminal
emulation,  file  transfers,  scripting,  etc., are all handled by the
comm  program.   Connecting  to  a  host  is as simple as typing "ATDT
abc.edu,23"  or  even  simpler if the host is in the comm's phonebook.
Also, with telser's built-in scripting, logins can be automated.